# WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks returns immediately without waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, threadpool, wait

What am I doing wrong here that WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks returns immediately without waiting?

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
...
PTP_WAIT Pwa = CreateThreadpoolWait(WaitCallback, NULL, NULL);
SetThreadpoolWait(Pwa, hEvent, NULL);
// Here we should wait until hEvent gets signaled
WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks(Pwa, FALSE);
// Here we should get after hEvent gets signaled
```

WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks never waits and execution continues right after WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks. However the callback still gets called any way if the event gets signaled. The event also gets signaled regardless of WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks was called before or not.

In SetThreadPoolWait Timeout is set to NULL to wait forever.

> A pointer to a FILETIME structure that specifies the absolute or
>   relative time at which the wait operation should time out. If this
>   parameter points to a positive value, it indicates the absolute time
>   since January 1, 1601 (UTC), in 100-nanosecond intervals. If this
>   parameter points to a negative value, it indicates the amount of time
>   to wait relative to the current time. For more information about time
>   values, see File Times.
>
> If this parameter points to 0, the wait times out immediately. If this
>   parameter is NULL, the wait will not time out.

**Edit:** It seems that a call of `SetThreadpoolWait` on its own will not set a Thread Pool Wait Item (PTP_WAIT) into pending state. If this would be the case, `WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks` would wait if CancelPendingCallbacks parameter is set to  FALSE. It could also the case that the word "Cancel Pending" is misleading. Pending could also mean that the event has been waiting for has already been signaled, but there was no free worker thread to start the callback method.

Another unlikely reason could be that `WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks` is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there might be a race condition:

From [MSDN Magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/november/windows-with-c-thread-pool-synchronization)

> The catch is that the wait object will only queue a callback when either the associated synchronization object is signaled or the timeout expires. Until one of those events occurs, no callbacks are queued and there’s nothing for the Wait function to wait for. The solution is to first call SetThreadpoolWait with null pointer values, telling the wait object to cease waiting, and then call WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks to avoid any race conditions:

```
SetThreadpoolWait(w.get(), nullptr, nullptr);
WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks(w.get(), TRUE);
```

Comment: The issue is that WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks waits for any callbacks that have been queued, but if the event hasn't been set yet, then nothing has been queued, and there is nothing to wait for. The article is talking about a race condition at shutdown, which is interesting but not the immediate question.